# MVC 4 Action Result er

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in Asp.net MVC 4

I write function using MVC controller

```
    public ActionResultRole_name(string role)
    {

        return role;
    }
```

My question is how to display return value on cshtml razor view?

Comment: First you read more article, tutorial. Research about pass model to view. You are very very new :) Check [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/04/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-pass-data-to-a-view.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You could return a ViewResult:

```
public ActionResult Role_name(string role)
{
    return View((object)role);
}
```

and in the corresponding `Role_name.cshtml` view you could use this value:

```
@model string
<div>The role is @Model</div>
```

Notice how it was necessary to cast the `role` variable to an `object` to ensure that the proper View method overload (taking a model) is being resolved.

On the other hand you could have used a view model which is always best practice:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

which your controller action could have populated and passed to the corresponding stringly typed view:

```
public ActionResult Role_name(string role)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Role = role;
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>The role is @Model.Role</div>
```

Also I would recommend you taking a look at some of the getting started tutorials on the [`asp.net/mvc`](http://asp.net/mvc) site.

Comment: Why is it necessary to cast a `string` to `object` when it is a `string` as the model?

Comment: @Monkieboy, because there's an overload of the View method which takes a string. And this string is NOT the model. It is the view name. So basically you have those 2 methods: `View(string viewName)` and `View(object model)`. And if you call `return View(role);` since `role` is a string you see which overload will get picked by the compiler. But if you follow best practices and use a view model, as shown in the second part of my answer, there won't be such ambiguity.

Comment: i tried to display on layout.cshtml page modelMyViewModel
The role is @Model.Role but its not working

Comment: @user1127905, the contrarcy to a view, the Layout is not strongly typed to a model because this Layout could be reused for multiple views which have different models. If you have some common part that you would like to display on all pages in the Layout you could use child actions. Phil Haack wrote a nice article here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx