# How do I render a string as an MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm on a team building a large ASP.NET MVC application. I'd like to have a place holder that shows the string "Not Yet Implemented" when a menu option is selected that has not been implemented by the team yet. I started by returning `this.Content("Not yet Implemented");` but this method does not render the layout which contains the menu so the testers are led into a dead end. Is there a way to render just that string inside the layout without creating a view? I don't want to create a view that's just going to be deleted when the project is complete.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry if I'm unclear here but the goal is to render an arbitrary string as a view. Suggesting I create a `.cshtml` file does not answer my question. I'm going to solve my problem by implementing the error handling and throwing the exception (which feels more "right" anyway). I'm leaving the question up anyway though because I'm curious if what I originally wanted to do is even possible.

Comment: What's wrong with an error page and a `throw new NotImplementedException()`?

Comment: youc an use Generic view in shared folder.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you could use:

```
return Content("Not yet Implemented");
```

But... you could add a View in Shared, and instead of returning `Content("XXX")` you call return `View("Shared/NotImplementedView");`

Similar to the previous one, if your action is there (since it will be called), you could also add a View but for now place the "`<h3>Not yet implemented</h3>`" markup as its content. Once implemented you could just replace its content. This way you don't need to specify the view name, just do `return View();`  (If the view has the same name as the action)

Comment: I've done that other places but due to the nature of how this section of the app is being put together (it's not worth going into I assure you) it won't work here.

Comment: So, maybe you need to explain something more, in order to be able to help you with a better option.

Comment: As I said in my EDIT above I'm curious if it's possible to render an arbitrary string as a view. If it's not possible that's fine but I'd like to know definitively.

Comment: I did't realize you edited the question... If the Content option could have an overload that include your layout could help you.

Comment: Yeah I feel like that should be a thing that exists but it doesn't appear to.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do:

```
string notImplementedYet = "Not implemented yet.";
return View((object)notImplementedYet);
```

Akin to what I was reminded by Darin Dimitrov the other day:

[MVC 4 Action Result er](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456898/mvc-4-action-result-er/16457019#comment23608330_16457019)

I personally would throw `NotImplementedException` or something more elegant than returning the string as a model though, but if it is for a holding page while in development I guess a string is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the ViewBag for this. In your server side, do this:

```
ViewBag.MyString = "hello world";
return View();
```

And in your markup:

```
@ViewBag.MyString
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is appropriate for what you're trying to do since all you want is to show the error on a page but here is a function that will allow you to render any razor view as a string:

```
 public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model = null)
 {
   ViewData.Model = model;
   using (sw == new System.IO.StringWriter())
   {
     dynamic viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
 dynamic viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
 viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
 return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
   }
 }
```

This will allow you to get any razor view as a string and then you can do anything you want with it. What is really cool about this is that you can pass in the model too...

Comment: But that is just the opposite of what he wants.